# AVAssetExportSession Error

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession

When i use avassetexportsession is works sometimes but other times it fails and i get the error below.  I looked online and the apple docs and can not find anything about this error.

Error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14dcf3bf0 
{Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12842 "(null)"},              
NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12842)
```

Code:

```
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(savedFileTest)
        EditSongViewController.url.urlComplete = url
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixedFile, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
        exporter!.audioMix = audioMixer
        exporter!.outputURL = url
        exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler( {
            // this handler gets called in a background thread!
            switch exporter!.status {
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
                self.indicator.stopAnimation(false, completion: nil)
                //println("failed url=\(exporter.outputURL), error=\(exporter.error)")
                return;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                self.indicator.stopAnimation(false, completion: nil)
                return;
            default:
                self.indicator.stopAnimation(false, completion: nil)
                Flurry.logEvent("Saved song To Phone")
                self.postOrSend(isPrivate)
            }})
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: no still haven't. I emailed apple support but they were no help just told me to submit a bug report. Let me know if you figure this out

Comment: hey dou you figure out this??